# why is my kafka consumer not showing any messages after i setup SASL_PLAINTEXT

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

so i installed kafka server and confirmed that they work when i just plainly test them

then i have to set up SASL_PLAINTEXT for the kafka
so i followed the instruction from [here](https://velog.io/@limsubin/Kafka-SASLPALIN-%EC%9D%B8%EC%A6%9D-%EC%84%A4%EC%A0%95%EC%9D%84-%ED%95%B4%EB%B3%B4%EC%9E%90)

which basically created

1. zookeeper_jaas.conf
   [image]
2. kafka_jaas.conf
   [image]

then add configuration to

1. zookeeper.properties

```
zookeeper.sasl.client=true
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

2. server.properties

```
super.users=User:admin
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://my_ip:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://my_ip:9092
```

and then adding the line `export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=file:$base_dir/../config/zookeeper_jaas.conf"` and `"kafka_jaas.conf"` accordingly in their ...-start.sh

then after starting zookeeper and kafka, i tried
[image]

but the consumer shows nothing
[image]

this is the consumer.properties
[image]

What am i missing?

kafka: version 3.5.0
zookeeper: version 3.6.4
ubuntu: Linux 5.15.0-82-generic

Comment: Were you able to fix it?? I am too facing same issue

Comment: @the_D I actually did, its been a while I don't quite remember what I did but I'll post what i wrote on my notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what I did, but I think I just reinstall things with different approach and it works

This is what I do:

1. Install

```bash
curl "https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.1.0/kafka_2.12-2.1.0.tgz" -o ~/Downloads/kafka2.tgz
mkdir kafka2
cd kafka2
tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/kafka2.tgz --strip 1
```

2. zookeeper service Configuration (zookeeper.service)

```bash
[Unit]
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
ExecStart=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. kafka service Configuration (kafka.service)

```bash
[Unit]
Requires=zookeeper.service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/kafka/kafka2/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka2/config/server.properties'
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka2/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and then I just start and stop it as a service

```bash
sudo service zookeeper start
sudo service kafka start
sudo service kafka status
sudo service kafka stop
```

**My testing Configuration**

My Kafka is in my vm and I need to connect to it from outside the vm

Configuration File: `kafka2/config/server.properties`

```bash
listeners={auth mechanism}://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners={auth mechanism}://myvm:9092
...
security.inter.broker.protocol={auth mechanism}
```

options (auth mechanism)

- SASL_SSL (SASL + TLS/SSL)
- SASL_PLAINTEXT (SASL only)
- SSL (TLS/SSL only)
- PLAINTEXT

**Additional Configuration**

1. Use TLS/SSL

```bash
ssl.truststore.location=/home/kafka/ssl/kafka.broker0.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/ssl/kafka.broker0.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.enabled.protocol=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
```

2. SASL

```
sasl.enabled.mechanisms={sasl mechanism}
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol={sasl mechanism}
```

options (sasl mechanism)

- PLAIN

```bash
# add to config file
listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin007" \
   user_admin="admin007";
```

- SCRAM-SHA-256

```bash
./kafka-configs.sh --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=admin007],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin007]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

```bash
# add to config file
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin007";
```

- SCRAM-SHA-512

```bash
./kafka-configs.sh --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=admin007],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=admin007]' --entity-type users --entity-name admin --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

```bash
# add to config file
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-512.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin007";
```